# C - Function processing a const *

Tags: c, pointers, constants

I have a function which search something in a const *. And returns such a const * to the found element. Therefore the function is not changing anything and I actually want to maintain the "const" for readability and reuseability. 
But I have another function which calls the function with just a * and then works with the returned value. But in this use-case the value should be changed. But because the returned value is a const * I can not do that.
Would should I adjust in my programming pattern to evade that problem?

```
const void* search_min_vector_element(const void* vector, size_t length, size_t element_size, int(*cmp_fnc) (const void*, const void*));
```

This is the first function.

```
void* min_element = search_min_vector_element((unsigned char*) vector + (i * element_size), length - i, element_size, cmp_fnc);
```

And that is the call in the second one. `vector` is void* in this case. And because of that I want to modify it.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is actually a shortcoming in the C language, which is why the standard `strchr` routine takes a `const char *` and returns `char *`. [Lundin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/584518/lundin)’s answer using `_Generic` is about the best you can do.

Answer (score 2):

You can pick which function to execute based on the type of the argument. Write a _Generic macro to select which types to allow, then call the appropriate function based on that. Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* print_str (char* str)
{
  printf("%s\n", str);
  return str;
}

const char* print_str_const (const char* str)
{
  printf("const %s\n", str);
  return str;
}

#define print(str)                       \
  _Generic((str),                        \
           const char*: print_str_const, \
           char*:       print_str) (str) 


int main(void)
{
  const char* cstr = "hello";
  char* str = "world";

  cstr = print(cstr);      // ok
  str = print(str);        // ok
  cstr = print(str);       // ok
//str = print(cstr);       // compiler error, incorrect assignment
//str = print((void*)str); // compiler error, wrong type
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you have a lot of options to deal with this. But since this is C, create another function is the best solution I can currently come up with:

```
const void* search_min_vector_element_const(const void* vector, size_t length, size_t element_size, int(*cmp_fnc) (const void*, const void*));
      void* search_min_vector_element      (      void* vector, size_t length, size_t element_size, int(*cmp_fnc) (      void*,       void*));
```

You can also force-cast the result directly:

```
void* min_element = (void*)search_min_vector_element((unsigned char*) vector + (i * element_size), length - i, element_size, cmp_fnc);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would really recommend to change the return type (if you can) to not be a constant value. It is really not the search_min_vector_element's business what another function shall do with the result.

If you cannot change the return type, then you will need to:

```
const void* value = search_min_vector_element(....)
void* second_no_const_value = *value; // copy value of the value pointed by    constant pointer.
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you know for a fact that you hold a non-const pointer to `vector`, you should simply cast the const pointer you receive:

```
void* min_element = (void*)search_min_vector_element(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically you may cast from `const char*` to `char*` through an explicit cast without yielding undefined behaviour per se; But if you alter a value that must not be altered (e.g. a string literal), you get undefined behaviour then. So the `const`-qualifier will not prohibit a change of the underlying data, but when used as qualifier in a function argument or return value, the function prototype pretends that the value is not meant to be altered.

Hence, if you - or a library - provides a function with return type `const char*`, without knowing the implementation, one shall not assume that the returned value points to memory that may be altered. See the following example illustrating this. Functions `validImpl1` and `validImpl2` have - apart from the name - the same signature but different implementations. Provided that you pass in a parameter which's content may be altered, casting the return value to `char*` for the first is OK, but for the second one it yields UB. So unless you know the internals of the function, you should never cast from `const char*` to `char *`:

```
const char* validImpl1(const char* t) {
    return t;
}

const char* validImpl2(const char* t) {
    return "Hello!";
}

int main() {

    char x[100] = "Herbert";
    char* t=(char*) validImpl1(x);
    *t = 'a'; // OK
    printf("%s\n",t);

    char* t2=(char*) validImpl2(x);
    *t2 = 'a';   // Undefined behaviour here.
    printf("%s\n",t2);
}
```

In your case, if you are the one offering the function and knowing about the implementation details, you could offer two functions, one with `const char*` and one with `char*`, where the latter simply calls the former. So the ones who use your functions can rely on that what the function prototypes pretend.

Comment: The C standard does not mention at all what happens if you cast away a qualifier during pointer conversion. Therefore it _is_ undefined behavior.

Comment: @Lundin: The standard explicitly says you may convert a pointer to an object type to a pointer to another object type, in 6.3.2.3 7. So it is not the conversion *per se* that is a problem. Further, that paragraph says that converting the pointer back results in a pointer equal to the original value, and it says converting to a pointer to a character type yields a pointer to the lowest addressed byte, so converting a `const char *` to a `char *` yields a pointer to the lowest address byte, which is the `char`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Then why did they write 6.3.2.3/2 in the first place? Seems like a completely redundant paragraph, if 6.3.2.3/7 is what matters anyway. Notably, 6.3.2.3/7 does not mention qualifiers at all.

Comment: @Lundin: 2 lets you add `const` to any pointed-to type. 7 does two things: (1) lets you use any type as a temporary holder for another type (e.g., convert pointer to `int` to pointer to `const int`, pass it to a routine, get it back, and convert it back to pointer to `int`) and (2) let you convert to a pointer to a character type. Thus, 2 and 7 do not cover converting a pointer to `const int` that did not originate as a pointer to `int` to a pointer to `int` and then using it (dereferencing it, not just converting it back).